# How to make a working img src from a local img src - PHP

Tags: php

I am using cURL to get the img srcs of all the img tags used in a website. But the website has many names specified without host names, like:

```
<img src="/images/look.jpg" />
<img src="i4.ytimg.com/vi/OmliBRZUxnk/maxresdefault.jpg?feature=og" title="youtube pic" />
```

So how do I determine which of the src's will render the pic without any manipulation of them, and which one will need to be prepended with the site's host name (steekcoders.com).

Currently I'm trying this:

```
$url = 'http://www.steekcoders.com'; $parse='http://'.parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST).'/'; $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

foreach($imgArray as $src)
{  
 $src=ltrim($src,"/"); if(empty($src)){ continue; }

if(!preg_match($reg_exUrl, $src))
{
 $clipouts[]=$src; $req="http://".$src; $extra=$parse.$src; 
 $clipouts[] = $extra; $clipouts[] = $req;
} 
else{ $clipouts[]=$src; {   

}
```

But it is not working out very well. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to use PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function. It returns an associative array with all of the values it found. You fill in the values that are missing, and voila!

```
php > var_dump(parse_url('/abc'));
array(1) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(4) "/abc"
}

php > var_dump(parse_url('http://a.b.c/abc'));
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(5) "a.b.c"
  ["path"]=>
  string(4) "/abc"
}
```